# Taylor-Series at point x = 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

We have
$$ f(x) = (1+x)^{1/3} $$

I have to find the taylor series of f at the point x =0. The problem I am facing is that I do not know how often do I have to derive f

$$ f'(x) = \frac{1}{3}(1+x)^{-2/3} $$
$$ f''(x) = -\frac{2}{9}(1+x)^{-5/3} $$
$$ f'''(x) = \frac{10}{27}(1+x)^{-8/3} $$
$$ f^{4}(x) = -\frac{80}{81}(1+x)^{-11/3}$$

As you can see, I can derive infinity times.
As you also can see, there is a certain pattern when you oberseve the derivatives. 
The pattern I recognised is something like that:

$$ f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{..}{3^n}(1+x)^{-\frac{3n-1}{3}} $$

I don't know what to put in ".." in the first fraction.

I also don't know if I am completely wrong or right. 
Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: $\prod\limits_{i=2}^{n}(2+3(i-2))$ for $n \geq 2$ and $1$ for $n=1$.

Comment: Well, is there an easier way to write that down? Because this would look very fancy as a numerator..

Comment: $$(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n$$ even if $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

From 
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{1}{3}(1+x)^{-\color{blue}{2}/3}\\
f''(x) &= -\frac{2}{9}(1+x)^{-\color{blue}{5}/3} \\
f'''(x) &= \frac{10}{27}(1+x)^{-\color{blue}{8}/3} \\
f^{4}(x) &= -\frac{80}{81}(1+x)^{-11/3}\\
\end{align*}
we conclude the numerator is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{2}\cdot \color{blue}{5}\cdot \color{blue}{8}=\prod_{j=1}^3 (3j-1)=8!!!
\end{align*}
with $n!!!=n\cdot  (n-3)\cdot (n-6)\cdots $ the *[triple factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials)*.

> In general $n$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>  f^{(n)}(x) &= (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^n (3j-1)}{3^n} (1+x)^{-\frac{3n-1}{3}} \\
>  &= (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(3n-1)!!!}{3^n} (1+x)^{-\frac{3n-1}{3}} 
> \end{align*}

Comment: Today I learned about the triple factorial. +1!!!

Comment: @ThomasR: Thanks! :-) Albeit triple factorial are rather seldom used, we met double factorial more often, e.g. when transforming $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}$ to $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following table, where the first column is the order of the derivative, and the second column the numerator of the fraction:
$$\begin{align}
1&\quad-1\\
2&\quad1\cdot2\\
3&\quad1\cdot2\cdot5\\
4&\quad1\cdot2\cdot5\cdot8\\
5&\quad1\cdot2\cdot5\cdot8\cdot11
\end{align}$$
Can you see the pattern?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't know the pattern at the third derivative. $$ 1*2*5$$ Could you give me a hint please?

Comment: Look at the sequence of the last factor: $1$, $2$, $5$, $8$, $11$,...

Comment: It is always +3 , but how to write that mathematically correct?

Comment: The last factor in the numerator of the $n$-th derivative is $3\,n-4$. You can write the numerator as $$(-1)\cdot2\cdot5\dots\cdot(3\,n-4)=\prod_{k=1}^n(3\,k-4).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\prod\limits_{i=0}^{i=n-2}(2+3i) = 3^{n-1}\prod\limits_{i=0}^{i=n-2}(i+\frac{2}{3}) = 3^{n-1}(n-2+\frac{2}{3})!=3^{n-1}(n-\frac{4}{3})!$